# Any changes I do in controller and model are not reflecting until I restart my rails server

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I have upgraded my rails app from rails 2x to 3.2.3. But facing a weird issue.
Any changes I do in controller and model are not reflecting until I restart my rails server. 
Caching is disabled in my development.rb as

`config.cache_classes = false`

`config.action_controller.perform_caching = false`

But it doesn't work. I even tried updating my rails version to 3.2.5

My application configuration is

Ruby version :  ruby 1.9.3p194 with RVM

Rails version : 3.2.3

Application server: webrick

Webserver: Apache

Thanks in advance

Comment: Are you trying this in development mode or production mode?

Comment: I am trying in Development mode

Comment: This may be obvious, but are you sure your changes are being saved (I've made this mistake...)? With your config file correct, there aren't many other places that would cause what you are describing.